Unifying the Faraday and Ampère law with complex fields
The Faraday and Ampère laws in a vacuum and in the absence of sources read, respectively,
$$
\operatorname{curl} E = -\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}\,,\qquad \operatorname{curl} B = \frac{\partial E}{\partial t}\,.
$$
Formally introducing a complex-valued field $u=E+iB$ leads to the single law
$$
\left(-i\frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \operatorname{curl}\right) u =0.\tag{1}
$$
Consider a stationary solution $$u(t,x) = e^{-it\lambda}u_0(x) \tag{2}$$ of (1), where $u_0(x) = E_0(x) + iB_0(x)$ is the initial configuration of the fields and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\operatorname{curl}$. Then
$$
u(t,x) = \left[E_0(x)\cos(t\lambda) + B_0(x)\sin(t\lambda)\right] + i\left[B_0(x)\cos(t\lambda) - E_0(x)\sin(t\lambda)\right]
$$
We interpret this to say that the electric and magnetic field "mix" as the stationary solution (2) evolves over time. Does this mean that the stationary solution (2) is unphysical? Or could this interpreted as a circularly polarised state in some way?

The "$E+iB$" combination is called the Riemann-Silberstein vector, see, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Silberstein_vector. If by an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of the $\operatorname{curl}$ you mean $\operatorname{curl}u_0 = \lambda u_0$ then your solution in (2)  is indeed a vector rotating, hence you may call it circularly polarized standing wave that is not a propagating wave. But of course you also need some boundary conditions along with the $\operatorname{curl} u_0=\lambda u_0$ to say that it is "solved".
